# Search for PDF files using PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf

I am trying to use a form I made for a webpage to search for PDF files that are in my file manager directory. Is there a way to have a user put in information in the form to pull up a specific PDF file?

Comment: On which OS you are running Apache, PHP ?

Comment: I am currently just using Windows 7. I am not using a server for this. Everything is stored and uploaded to my online directory.

Comment: Still its unclear. Could you please give more details. How are managing "Online Directory"? Do you want to search from PDF or search for PDF files?? Where is source located? Is it uploaded by user? What data do you have in DB?

Answer (score 0):

[glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) is a very powerful PHP function for listing your directory contents. You can provide a pattern to match filenames against.

```
var_dump(glob('/path/to/files/*.pdf'));
```

If you need to search subdirectories as well, try this commenter's recursive solution: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#106595

Then you need to come up with the best algorithm for filtering the result set. You could take the user's input and match filenames against it:

```
$pdfs = glob('/path/to/files/*.pdf'));
$results = array_filter($pdfs, function ($pdf) {
    return stripos($pdf, $_GET['q']) !== false;
});
var_dump($results);
```

This will simply check to see if the user's query (`$_GET['q']`) is somewhere in the name of the file (case-insensitive). You may require a more robust solution.